# Knockout - resetting an observable array of observables

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

I have an observable array of observables as follows

```
appViewModel.rollArray = ko.observableArray([{
        diceAmount: ko.numericObservable(1),
        diceType: ko.observable(null),
        diceAddition: ko.numericObservable(0),
        diceMultiplication: ko.numericObservable(1)
    }]);
```

There are bindings that are watching for these properties as well such as the following

```
<input type="number" data-bind="value: rollArray()[rollIndex()].diceAmount" />
```

This array gets populated and changed quite a bit in the web application, but I am in need of having a "reset" button. Which will restore the appViewModel.rollArray to its default state (as I defined above).  The problem is that if I simply re-define rollArray, then the bindings all cease to function.  Likewise if I try and do removeAll() from rollArray and then push in a object of default values, then the bindings are immediately notified after removeAll and generate errors because they cannot find those properties inside of the array.

Is there a good way of solving this issue?

**Current solution**

It isn't elegant (and thus the reason for me asking here on SO) but currently I simply push a new element onto the modified array, then splice everything else off.

```
appViewModel.rollArray.push({
            diceAmount: ko.numericObservable(1),
            diceType: ko.observable(null),
            diceAddition: ko.numericObservable(0),
            diceMultiplication: ko.numericObservable(1)
        });
appViewModel.rollArray.splice(0,appViewModel.rollArray().length-1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of push/splice, you can just re-assign the array value:

```
appViewModel.rollArray([{
    diceAmount: ko.numericObservable(1),
    diceType: ko.observable(null),
    diceAddition: ko.numericObservable(0),
    diceMultiplication: ko.numericObservable(1)
}]);
```